# How do I empty a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to pandas could someone please let me know how I empty a data-frame of all data please?

Comment: And why do you need that? Why cannot you just set it to `None` or something?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here? You can call `del df` or assign the df to `None` as already suggested. Otherwise you could assign it to an empty df with the same index and columns `df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns = df.columns)` or `df.loc[:] = NaN`

Comment: Expanding slightly on EdChum's comment you can "empty" the dataframe in at least 4 possible ways:  `df[:] = 0`, `df[:] = ''`, `df[:] = np.nan`, or `df[:] = None`,

Answer (score 2):

Either you use `.loc` to set all values to `None`

```
df.loc[:] = None
```

Or if you want to be more explicit

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=full_df.columns, index=full_df.index)
```

Speed wise the `.loc` is a lot faster, but unless your are doing this many many times, or your dataframe is really large, you will not see a difference.

```
n = 500000

values = np.random.uniform(size=(n, 5))

def using_loc():
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=list('abcde'))
    df.loc[:] = None
%timeit using_loc()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop

def new_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=list('abcde'))
    pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
%timeit new_df()
# 10 loops, best of 3: 45.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: The `data=None` is not required it's the [default value](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) anyway

Comment: Quoting from the zen of python, second line "Explicit is better than implicit."